# how to work in development environment for nestjs with docker?

Tags: docker, nestjs

I am new to docker and in development environment when i make changes it didn't reflect it return me an old result to see new changes i have to create build again.
Project is created in nestJs with mongodb as database

Below is my docker-composer.yml

```
version: '3.4'

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: local
  eventstore-data:
    driver: local
  eventstore-logs:
    driver: local
  mongodb:
    driver: local

services:
  ----,
  api:
    build:
      context: ../api
    hostname: tracking_code_api
    ports:
      - '${APP_PORT}:3000'
    environment:
      - APP_URL=${APP_URL}
      - APP_PORT=${APP_PORT}
      - API_VERSION=${API_VERSION}
      - AMQP_HOST=${AMQP_HOST}
      - AMQP_PORT=${AMQP_PORT}
      - AMQP_USERNAME=${AMQP_USERNAME}
      - AMQP_PASSWORD=${AMQP_PASSWORD}
      - AMQP_EXCHANGES=${AMQP_EXCHANGES}
      - MONGO_DB_TYPE=${MONGO_DB_TYPE}
      - MONGO_DB_HOST=${MONGO_DB_HOST}
      - MONGO_DB_PORT=${MONGO_DB_PORT}
      - MONGO_DB_USERNAME=${MONGO_DB_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=${MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}
      - MONGO_DB_NAME=${MONGO_DB_NAME}
      - MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE=${MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE}
      - MONGO_AUTH_MECHANISM=${MONGO_AUTH_MECHANISM}
      - ACCESS_TOKEN=${ACCESS_TOKEN}
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
      - eventstore
      - mongodb
```

And this is my dockerFile

```
FROM node:14.4.0-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package files
COPY package*.json ./

# Install npm packages
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Build our app for production
RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:prod" ]
```

Comment: You should be able to use `node` on your host like normal for day-to-day development, even if you're running the database dependencies in containers.  Set the environment variables to point at `localhost` and the published `ports:` for the dependency services.

Comment: What changes? Changes to the code? Why wouldn't you need to build the container again to see them? Please explain more clearly what you were trying to do, what behaviour you think is wrong and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: are you facing problem in development environment like to see changes have to re build again ?

Comment: yes i am facing problem in development environment

Comment: @TomW like you normally do npm run start to working in development environment but in project i run command docker-composer up then changes in code it does not reflect in browser or result through postman i have create build again with docker-composer up --build to see changes